# Don't update Firebase data after first load

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewcontroller

I'm using firebase to store data from my iOS app. This data stored to my database are also readable from the app. There is view controller (B) which stores data with a button and a view controller (A) which show that data. I want either to kill the view controller (A) when i'm on (B) and the opposite or update (A) at the startup one time (as it does) and after that never update again. I want to do that because I have error sending data from (B) to my database. Sorry for my English.

**Error :)** : *popViewControllerAnimated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.*

Comment: your error has nothing to do with firebase.

Comment: @rv7284 what to do then? What's that error?

Comment: The error is about view controller being popped while Some other transaction is being occurred. And the problem regarding Firebase is still not clear

Comment: My table view (A) loads data from firebase. I want to stop updating after first load. That's what i mean. Open -> load data from firebase(don't update that data again) -> close the app.. then open it and do the same, load new data etc.

Comment: Than load the data in ViewDidLoad

Comment: That's what i do..I'll update my question in 10 minutes